# Preload CSS images at a certain point

Tags: html, css, load, preloader

Obviously this could be done on window load, but I'm only allowed to start loading CSS background image assets after another library loads, like so:

> 1. Load HTML/basic CSS/ad publisher JS
> 2. Once ad publisher JS is loaded, I need to call another CSS file, so I append it to the head of the document
> 3. At this point window is already loaded, but a new CSS file was included with assets linked to it that now need to be preloaded

As you can see I need to load the CSS file + the images linked within at a certain point after window has loaded

I tried a few image preloaders but nothing seems to work the way I need it to. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure why you can't achieve this by positioning the different elements within the dom in different places. You can load the image after the opening body tag, it's an old trick used for backgrounds. Make sure to hide if off screen with a display none.

```
<head>
    <script>
        /*load my js css*/
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<img class="myimage" style="display:none;">
<script>
    /* Load a different script that will be able to reference myimage.*/
</script>
</body>
```

I'm not 100% sure I read your question right, but you can alway load css outside the head as well if you're ok with "breaking the rules"